# How to classify float as grades

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to programming and have run into a bit of problem. Hoping I can get help for thge question below:

I have a dictionary comprising names and grades. The question says  "create a function, which will take as input a grade as a float, and output a string which denotes the grade classification.
E.g.
< 40.0 is a “Fail”
40.0 - 50.0 is a “Pass”
50.0 - 60.0 is “2:2”
60.0-70.0 is a “2:1”
70.0 is a “First”

Create a dictionary comprehension which will apply grade_to_classification for every value. Hint: {k: v ... Would store the value, v, at the key k. We want to store the return of grade_to_classification on that grade (I.e. grade_to_classification(v) in this case)

This is the code I have written but it gives me {} as answer.

```
student_records : {'Ada': 98.0, 'Bill': 45.0, 'Charlie': 63.2, 'Teri': 35.0, 'Johanna': 52.5, 'Tomas': 37.8, 'Piotr': 65.0, 'Grzegorz': 64.8}

name = student_records.keys()
grade = student_records.values()

def grade_to_classification(grade):
    if grade < 40.0: return "Fail"
    elif grade >40.0 and v <50.0: return "Pass"
    elif grade >50.0 and v <60.0: return "2.2"
    elif grade >60.0 and v <70.0: return "2.1"
    elif grade >70.0: return "First"

classified_student_records = {k:grade_to_classification(v) for k, v in student_records.items() if v== float}
print(classified_student_records)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nearly working. There are two issues here. First, remove the `if v == float` entirely, that is unnecessary.

Once you fix that you will notice an error about an unrecognized symbol(specifically, a `NameError`) , and seeing as this appears to be homework I'll let you try that out first and see if you can solve it.

Hint: This error occurs when you reference something that does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much. I replaced the v in my if statements and that sorted it out. You guys rock!

Comment: @Grace If you don't mind accepting the answer (the checkmark on the left) to close this off that'd be great. No problem!

Answer (score 2):

The `v == float` will always be false.  What I think you want is `isinstance(v, float)` -- although even this is unnecessary because you already know that all the values are floats.

Comment: if i take out ```if v == float``` , it tells me v is not defined. When i used ```isinstance(v, float)``` , i get invalid syntax

Comment: Are you getting that error on the line with the comprehension where `v` is defined, or inside your function (where the value is bound to the name `grade`, not `v`)?